# Joining the same table with calculated fields returns "duplicated" rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to join the same table to sum certain field for each row with the others of the same table.

The problem is that I have row 1 summed with row 2, but the query, when it achieve row 2, gives me another row where it sums row 2 with row 1.

Example:

```
TABLE

 id       client      quantity

  1       john            2
  2       dave            6
  3       carl            4
  4       david           3
```

I join the same table to have the sum of quantity of each row with each others but the result gives me

```
TABLE

idClient1   idClient2  quantity1   quantity2     sum
   
   1           2          2            6          8  
   2           1          6            2          8   
...
```

In this case I have the first row with the sum of idClient1 = 1 + idClient2 = 2, so I don't need the sum of idClient1 = 2 + idClient2 = 1 because the second one is equal to the first one.

How can I avoid that query gives me 2 times the same couple of IdClient1 and idClient2 summed?

Comment: Please add the expected result of your example. It's not easy to tell what do you want.

Comment: The result I want Is to avoid the second row, because Is the same of the first. Joining the same table without "on" condition each row Is joined to all rows and it's what I need to compare the Sum of certain field, but the problem Is that row 1 Is joined with the second so I have the Sum ti compare, but Aldo the second row Is joined with the First One and I have the same Sum Teo times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  a.client as client1, 
  b.client as client2,
  a.quantity as quantity1,
  b.quantity as quantity2 
from my_table a
join my_table b on a.client < b.client
```

Result:

```
 client1  client2  quantity1  quantity2 
 -------- -------- ---------- --------- 
 david    john     3          2         
 carl     john     4          2         
 dave     john     6          2         
 carl     dave     4          6         
 carl     david    4          3         
 dave     david    6          3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16f485add17ac86fc0782a6314696c84).

The key is in the join predicate. It uses inequality to filter out symmetric pairs.

Comment: This reolve my issue, I got Just half of results of the original query so duplicates results was gone ! Thanks mate, I got a new skill today!